# Телеграм бот aiogram в канале

Tags: python, telegram, callback, aiogram-3.x

У меня есть телеграм канал. Через бота на python aiogram3 делаю пост с четырьмя инлайн кнопками (1, 2, 3, 4) и определенным текстом-пояснением для кнопок,
при нажатии на кнопки в разных постах у меня выводится одинаковый Callback ко всем постам:

- 1 пост - (нажал 1 - Аааа, нажал 2 - Ббб...т.д) сюда через state делал 1. Аааа, 2. Ббб...
- 2 пост - (нажал 1 - Аааа, нажал 2 - Ббб...т.д) сюда через state делал 1. Ееее, 2. Жжж...

Как сделать чтобы callback.answer выводил к каждому посту свой текст?
Например:

1. пост (нажали на одну из четырех кнопок - вывелось "Да, правильно, это Гоголь")
2. пост (нажали на одну из четырех кнопок - вывелось "Да, Молодец, это Бунин")

С помощью бота планируется выкладывать много постов